# How to compare element values between two Ordered Dictionaries

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare the values in the elements of two ordered dictionaries.  I am unable to find the right coding to get at the elements at index 0 and convert them into DictionaryEntrys.  I am trying to use the following code:

```
DictionaryEntry card1 = (DictionaryEntry)(player1.Hand[0]); 
DictionaryEntry card2 = (DictionaryEntry)(player2.Hand[0]);


if ((int)card1.Value > (int)card2.Value)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The code passes intellisense, but blows up with an invalid cast.  I can also code

```
 var card1 = player1.Hand[0];
```

but it won't allow me to retrieve card1.Value.  So far as I can tell, card1 needs to be converted to a DictionaryEntry, and I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: can you do `player1.Hand[0].Value` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in another thread, which helped me get at both key and value in the Ordered Dictionary:

```
DictionaryEntry card1 = player1.Hand.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(0);
```

thus card1.Key == key
and  card1.Value == value

Answer (score 6):

The indexer in `OrderedDictionary` is implemented as follows:

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get { return ((DictionaryEntry)objectsArray[index]).Value; }
    set { ... }
}
```

It's returning the value, not the key/value pair. That's why you can't cast it to a `DictionaryEntry`.

Do your comparison like this instead, casting the return value of the indexer directly to `int`:

```
if ((int)player1.Hand[0] > (int)player2.Hand[0])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

From your comment, it sounds like you want to be able to modify the key too.

AFAIK, you'll have to use the key or index to get the value, then remove the old element and add/insert the new one:

```
 var value = (int)player1.Hand[0];
 player1.Hand.RemoveAt(0);
 player1.Hand.Add("someNewKey", value);

 var value = (int)player1.Hand["oldKey"];
 player1.Hand.Remove("oldKey");
 player1.Hand.Add("someNewKey", value);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful.  Still, I need  to access both the Key and Value of the elements in the ordered dictionary, so that I can do Adds, Removes and Inserts.  The only way I know to do that now is with a foreach statement, e.g. foreach DictionaryEntry card in Player1.Hand, but that is very awkward for the code I am using.  Is there a more direct way to access the Key and Value of a single element in an ordered dictionary?

Comment: Thanks for your help.